# Assistance Required With Bash Script Execution

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script that pulls in comma delimited information from a file and prepares update statement. The file is setup to look like below:

```
ID,NAME,DATE,TIME,HOURS,EMPNUMBER
1, Joe, 12/11, 12:45, 5, 333
2, John, 12/12, 16:45, 7, 666
```

My script takes a file as the parameter and is run from the command line like below:

```
./runScript.sh file.csv
```

My script code is below:

```
for i in ` cat $1 | grep -v “EMPNUMBER” | cut -d',' -f4,5`
do
   time=`echo $i | cut -d',' -f1`
   hours=`echo $i | cut -d',' -f2`
   echo "update jobs.j j set j.time= $time where j.hours=$hours;"

done
```

I’m just curious why, when I run my script that it skips over the top line in my file which is the header information. Obviously, this is the desired effect but in order for my learning to progress I need to understand why the first line is skipped from the file.

Can someone assist in my understanding?
~

Comment: The `grep -v` command is removing that line.

Comment: and to learn how such scripts work, copy paste 1 line, command at a time into a terminal and observe the outputs. So `cat file` , tor hen `cat file | grep -v "EMPNUM"`, then cat file | grep -v EMPNUM | cut -d',' -f4,5`., etc etc. Also `set -vx` near the top of the script will show each line or block of script before it is executed, then each step that is executes is shown with a leading `+` and all variable substituted with their current values. Good luck.

Comment: To really see what is happening in your script during execution, on the line immediately below `#!/bin/bash` add the line `set -x` which will cause bash to output all variables and operations for each line in the script.

Answer (score 1):

If you are learning bash, then in addition to explaining that `grep -v "EMPNUM"` is what causes the header to be skipped (the `-v` option meaning find lines that **do not include** `EMPNUM`), there are a few other items to point out. First, good bash code utilizes the tools bash provides for reading input and parsing data rather than relying on spawning subshells to run additional programs (i.e. `cat, grep, cut`).

**Note:** there is nothing wrong with using `cat, grep, cut`, but recognizing that bash itself provides tools that do exactly what you are using those 3 other programs for will strengthen your programming skills.

First, bash provides the builtin `read` for reading data from `stdin` or any other file. To read a file, you generally see `while read var1 var2; do... done <"filename"` instead of `for i in $(cat file)` -- for many reasons. Next, rather than calling `cut...`, bash provides `parameter expansion/substring extraction` to handle parsing any line of text into any individual variables. Further, by choosing variables to accompany `read` wisely, you can eliminate needing to use `substring extraction` entirely.

The following shows the use of the bash alternatives to the `cat, grep, cut` approach shown in your example. If you are interested in learning `bash`, give it a look and let me know if you have any questions. You can use `echo` and `printf` interchangeably for output. While `echo` is generally simpler, `printf` provides a number of advantages. It is worth learning both...

```
#!/bin/bash

## set the datafile name (defaults to 'dat/empdata.dat')
dfn="${1:-dat/empdata.dat}"

## validate that file is readable
[ -r "$dfn" ] || {
    printf "\n error: file not readable '%s'. Usage: %s [filename (dat/empdata.dat)]\n\n" "$dfn" "${0//*\//}"
    exit 1
}

## simple output header for data
printf "\nEmployee data read from file: '%s'\n\n" "$dfn"

## read each line in file, skipping header (where $id = ID)
#  IFS is set to include ',' in addition to default ' \t\n'
while IFS=$' ,\t\n' read -r id nm dt tm hrs eno || [ -n "$hrs" ]; do

    # if header row - skip
    [ "$id" = "ID" ] && continue
    # print out each of the values for the employee
    printf "ID: %s  NAME: %-4s  DATE: %s  TIME: %s  HOURS: %s  EMPNUMBER: %s\n" \
    "$id" "$nm" "$dt" "$tm" "$hrs" "$eno"

done <"$dfn"
```

**input file:**

```
$ cat dat/empdata.dat
ID,NAME,DATE,TIME,HOURS,EMPNUMBER
1, Joe, 12/11, 12:45, 5, 333
2, John, 12/12, 16:45, 7, 666
```

**output:**

```
$ bash empdata.sh

Employee data read from file: 'dat/empdata.dat'

ID: 1  NAME: Joe   DATE: 12/11  TIME: 12:45  HOURS: 5  EMPNUMBER: 333
ID: 2  NAME: John  DATE: 12/12  TIME: 16:45  HOURS: 7  EMPNUMBER: 666
```

Answer (score 0):

using awk, i tried

```
awk -F ',' '{if(NR==1) for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]=$i}{if(NR>=2)for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%s:%s\t",a[i],$i)}{printf("\n")}' file.txt
```

output:

```
ID:1    NAME: Joe   DATE: 12/11 TIME: 12:45 HOURS: 5    EMPNUMBER: 333  
ID:2    NAME: John  DATE: 12/12 TIME: 16:45 HOURS: 7    EMPNUMBER: 666
```